# How do I convert string to time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of type `varchar` with a time on it like `120217`. I would like to convert this to a time format I can query. Would something like

`alter table public.table alter column col_time type date using to_date(col_time, 'HHMMSS');`

work?

Comment: does this work as meant `alter table public.table alter column col_time type date using (col_time)::time;` ?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do:

```
alter table public.table 
alter column col_time 
type time using (col_time::time);
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what's wrong with the solution I posted, just to learn of the difference?

Comment: to tell that I have to see error or output of your statement. I just decided to use implicit cast. `to_date` returns date - I suppose it just ignores your HHMMSS mask: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: your solution gives me 
`ERROR:  result of USING clause for column "col_time" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to add an explicit cast.`

Comment: you probaby have int in col_time then. but then you should have error when trying to run `to_date(int, text)`... anyway - updated answer with explicit cast

Comment: @DervinThunk - obviously no implicit conversion date to time. Missed it because did not mock up column. Thank you for edit!